# Fundamental difference between jivan mukta and saguna parabrahman

Tags: brahman, moksha

Saguna parabrahman is a parabrahman with gunas (say Krishna).

Jivan mukta is a person who attained moksha but living due to prarabda (say Jada bharata).

What is the fundamental difference between a jivan mukta and saguna brahman?

Comment: Jivan mukta is a jiva and can never be equal to saguna Brahman.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that even saguNa brahman/Ishwara has no power over the jIvanmukta. This is according to advaita, of course. I will try to find the reference.

Comment: Jivanmukta will become Brahman in future and is in Turiya. Saguna Brahman manifests when the infinite Brahman takes a form for some purpose.

Answer (score 2):

No Jiva, however, spiritually advanced can equal Saguna Brahman.The fundamental difference is in shakti.

> All is Brahman, the One without a second; only the Brahman, as unity
>   or absolute, is too much of an abstraction to be loved and worshipped;
>   so the Bhakta chooses the relative aspect of Brahman, that is Ishvara,
>   the Supreme Ruler. To use a simile: Brahman is as the clay or substance
>   out of which an infinite variety of articles are fashioned. As clay,
>   they are all one; but form or manifestation differentiates them.
>   Before everyone of them was made, they all existed potentially in the
>   clay, and, of course, they are identical substantially; but when
>   formed, and so long as the form remains, they are separate and
>   different; **the clay-mouse can never become a clay-elephant, because,
>   as manifestations, form alone makes them what they are, though as
>   unformed clay they are all one.** Ishvara is the highest manifestation
>   of the Absolute Reality, or in other words, the highest possible
>   reading of the Absolute by the human mind.

Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 3, 37-42

Comment: So what happens when jivan mukta drops his body? Will he merge in Nirguna Brahman then?

Comment: Jivan mukta is free to do what he wants. He might choose to remain merged with Brahman or he might choose to maintain a subtle body and remain in duality.